# Having problems with infowindow.setContent and OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have been palying around with OVerlappingMArkerSpiderfier

https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

I have a loop that adds markers, but each marker needs an infoWindow to have some unique text as its content.

If I do the following:

```
content = '<div id="info">' +
                '<p><b><?php echo $row->Event ?></b></p>' +
                '<p><?php echo $row->Date ?></br>' +
                '<?php echo $row->City . ", " . $row->Country ?></p>' +
                '</div>';

oms.addListener('click', function(myMarker) {
         if(!iw){
            iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
         };

       iw.setContent(content);
      //  iw.setContent(myMarker.title);
        iw.open(map, myMarker);
      });
```

This only puts the last event in the infowindow.

If I try to do this:

```
(function(content, myMarker){
    oms.addListener('click', function(myMarker) {
         if(!iw){
            iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
         };

       iw.setContent(content);
      //  iw.setContent(myMarker.title);
        iw.open(map, myMarker);
      });
})();
```

...doesn't work at all

Can anyone shed some light.

I failed to mention: I'm relatively new to javascript.

Answer (score 4):

First, I would set `iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();` outside of the function to avoid your `if(!iw)` check.

Second, `oms.addListener` applies to all markers, not just one so this should not be within your loop of results (I'm assuming this is withing a while $row=$results type loop).

To make the correct content appear, you'll want to do something like `marker.desc = content` inside your loop, then inside the addListener do `iw.setContent(myMarker.desc);`

So something like this:

```
iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

oms.addListener('click', function(myMarker) {
    iw.setContent(myMarker.desc);
    iw.open(map, myMarker);
});

<?php while... { ?>
    ...
    content = '<div id="info">' +
        '<p><b><?php echo $row->Event ?></b></p>' +
        '<p><?php echo $row->Date ?></br>' +
        '<?php echo $row->City . ", " . $row->Country ?></p>' +
    '</div>';
    ...
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        ...
        ...
    });
    marker.desc = content;
    oms.addMarker(marker);
<?php } ?>
```